# Using object reference in CSS

Tags: css, oop, inheritance, colors, reference

I want to make a reference object in CSS, so that I can use the same object in other style sheets. Example would be, I am declaring a CSS object name like .my-bg{color :#B92241;} . In my other CSS , If I refer something like my-bg.color , the Color defined in that CSS should apply. In short, whenever I change the property in class my-bg, it should reflect all the CSS referencing the property name. I'm new to CSS, so excuse if I have used terms wrongly.

Comment: Are you sure that there are not another property who overwrite your color property? You should look at this article about priority: http://web-profile.com.ua/css/docs/css-styles-priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in pure CSS. You can however do this in two ways using a CSS preprocessor, such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

You can either declare variables:

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

..or use mixins:

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
     -moz-border-radius: $radius;
      -ms-border-radius: $radius;
          border-radius: $radius;
}

.box { @include border-radius(10px); }
```

Comment: Or if you like to live on the egde - [FF uses CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)